# Only allow specific characters in input

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have an input tag like so:

```
<input type="text" name="eventstarttime" list="eventstarttime" placeholder="Start Time" required>
```

and for this, it is allowed to have the time in it, so anywhere from `00:00` to `12:00`. but i basiclly want to also allow people to type in there time, but i want it to be constrainted to only being allowed to type in either one of the values that is presented in the `datalist` based on the javascript i have, or only allows them to type in a time between the said times above. here is the js:

```
<% var arrayOfTimes = []; %>                  
              <% for (var i = 0; i <= 48; i++) { %>
                <% var n = Math.floor(i/4) + [":00", ":15", ":30", ":45"][i%4]; %>
                <% if(n<10) %>
                    <% n = ''+n; %>
                <% arrayOfTimes.push(n); %>
                <% console.log(arrayOfTimes); %>
              <% } %>
              <input type="text" name="eventstarttime" list="eventstarttime" placeholder="Start Time" required>
              <datalist id="eventstarttime" required>
                <% for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfTimes.length; i++) { %>
                  <option value="<%= arrayOfTimes[i] %>">
                <% } %>
              </datalist>
```

and the returned results are like so:

```
[
  '0:00',  '0:15',  '0:30',  '0:45',  '1:00',
  '1:15',  '1:30',  '1:45',  '2:00',  '2:15',
  '2:30',  '2:45',  '3:00',  '3:15',  '3:30',
  '3:45',  '4:00',  '4:15',  '4:30',  '4:45',
  '5:00',  '5:15',  '5:30',  '5:45',  '6:00',
  '6:15',  '6:30',  '6:45',  '7:00',  '7:15',
  '7:30',  '7:45',  '8:00',  '8:15',  '8:30',
  '8:45',  '9:00',  '9:15',  '9:30',  '9:45',
  '10:00', '10:15', '10:30', '10:45', '11:00',
  '11:15', '11:30', '11:45', '12:00'
]
```

so i would want them to only be able to type in one of those values essentially. Now my question is, can i do this directly through the `input` tag, like specificy the number of charcaters and the type of characters, or does it have to be done through js? Wasn't able to find anything online.

Comment: Are you aware of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input:invalid+span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '✖';
  padding-left: 5px;
}

input:valid+span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '✓';
  padding-left: 5px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<label>Choose a time for your meeting:
<div>
  <input type="time" name="time"
       min="00:00" max="12:00" step="900" required>
   <span class="validity"></span>
 </div>
  <small>from 00:00 to 12:00</small>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use the `pattern` attribute on the `<input>` element. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern)

Input any *time* **not** in your list and it should prompt you to input the requested pattern. When you input one of the *times* it will not prompt you. You'll need to hit the `submit` button to see the prompt.

Note: times in this input may begin with `00` (like 00:15).

```js
document.forms[0].onsubmit = e =>e.preventDefault();
```

```html
<form>
<input pattern="[01]?[0-9]:(15|30|45|00)" placeholder="XX:XX (quarter hour)">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```